# Cakephp application displays incorrect path on ec2

Tags: php, css, cakephp, path, amazon-ec2

I have a cakephp project under folder name FC which contains app folder, index.php etc. which i uploaded on ubuntu instance on ec2. When I uploaded the folder, it was showing index folder so I uploaded the contents directly under FC into www folder so it could get index.php file automatically. Now the website started displaying but plain, without css or images or js. I looked at error log, and it's displaying this:

[Wed Aug 28 14:15:56 2013] [error] [client xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx] File does not exist: /var/www/js, referer: http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.compute.amazonaws.com/

[Wed Aug 28 14:15:56 2013] [error] [client xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx] File does not exist: /var/www/js, referer: http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.compute.amazonaws.com/

Clearly this shows that the paths are being set incorrectly. Now the path I've given for my js and images is in webroot folder, so I have my images in img folder and js in js folder under webroot so as path i just provide "filename.whatever" and that worked fine on localhost.
How do I need to set my paths so they will point to the correct place? When I inspect element on a botched image, it shows path /img/xxxx.jpg. Which means cake automatcally goes into image/js/css folder which is how my code was working on local machine. Now when I manually give path, like /www/app/webroot/img/xxx.jpg, it attaches itlike this: img/www/app/...etc. Please help! Is there documentation available on this or if someone has done this before?

EDITED:
**webroot/index.php:**

```
if (!defined('DS')) {
    define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
} 

define('ROOT', '/var/www/FC');   

define('APP_DIR', 'app');

define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', DS . 'var' . DS . 'www' . DS . 'FC' . DS . 'lib');
```

*BELOW THIS IS STANDARD CONTENT OF INDEX.PHP WHICH IT WRITTEN NOT TO CHANGE*

**sites-available/Default:**

```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/FC/app/webroot
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride All
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

By the way, my Index.ctp redirects to multiple links which are located in LocationsController including index.ctp, whereas cake is trying to find FCController. Do i need to rename locationscont to FCcont to match conventions maybe?

**I just found out, the urls inside the view and controller etc. all start like this '/FC/locations/...etc.' Do I need to give urls from base path, ie '/var/www/FC...' ?? **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using apache your publicly accessible folder by default is `/var/www/`

The following instructions will change the documentroot and setup cake in the simplest way to get you started.

First stop your apache server for security reasons while you prepare everything.

```
sudo service apache2 stop
```

Then copy your project in `/var/www/myproject`. That means that you will be able to find the webroot in `/var/www/myproject/app/webroot`. Of course `myproject` can be any folder you wish, just stick to the same in all commands if you change it.

You will need to tell the app where to find cakePHP:

```
nano /var/www/myproject/app/webroot/index.php
```

Go to the line starting with `define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH'` and make it `define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', DS . 'var' . DS . 'www' . DS . myproject . DS . cakephp . DS . lib')` - assuming `cakephp/lib` is to be found in `/var/www/myproject/cakephp/lib` or else amend as necessary.

Then tell apache what the new document root is:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

and wherever you see `/var/www` change it to `/var/www/myproject/app/webroot`.

Just to be certain that the web service (apache) can access your files and write to cache, execute the following commands:

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/myproject -R
sudo chmod 777 /var/www/myproject/tmp -R
```

Finally start your apache again:

```
sudo service apache2 start
```

If you now go to `http://xxx.compute.amazonaws.com/` all should work.

If you don't see CSS applied, you need to enable the rewrite module:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite && sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Super! It is displaying most of the code. However, I can only access the index.php file, and when I go to a link it shows incorrect path, ie.
/var/www/myproject/locations/ 
Instead it should display 
/var/www/myproject/app/locations
Which tells me that the location set for app folder is incorrect...where do I change it? Many thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is, can you be more specific?

Comment: Myproject folder name is FC for me, such that /var/www/FC/app is app location.

Now when I switched debugging to 2 in core.php, and click on any link, this is the error displayed:

Error: FCController could not be found.
Error: Create the class FCController below in file: app/Controller/FCController.php

<?php
class FCController extends AppController {

}

I have no file called FCController and this isn't my code, what do I do?

Comment: how are you trying to access the app via the URL?

Comment: Hey, I've figured the problem is coming due to path not being set in webroot's index:

The full path to the directory which holds "app", WITHOUT a trailing DS.
define('ROOT', dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))));

// The actual directory name for the "app".


define('APP_DIR', basename(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))));


 So if the path to my cake folder is this: /var/www/FC/app/webroot What do I write in the two lines? I tried giving the path but it didnt work, can you please give me specific command acc to the path i gave above? Thanks so much!

Comment: You normally don't need to touch anything else other than what I said. Please tell me how you're trying to access the url (what you put in the browser). Also update your original post to include  `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` and `/var/www/FC/app/webroot/index.php`. If you changed any other file, reset it to the original until we sort this out.

Comment: default and index.php added above. You have been the kindest, i can't thank you enough! In the URL I simply put the address of the instance, ie. ec2-13819handasd.amazonaws.com      No subdirectories in there. I've cleared out everything and installed it again such that /var/www/FC/app/webroot is my path. Previously, I did however change allowoverride None to All besides what you said, that started displaying other links but I started facing FCcontroller not found issues.

Comment: In your `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` you need to change the 8th line into `<Directory /var/www/FC>`. I said to change `/var/www` wherever you see it but perhaps it wasn't clear or you missed it. Good job changing `AllowOverride All` obviously without it rewrite won't work.

Comment: Hey! I fixed it!! Yeah I missed the /var/www and i corrected that. It turned out to be the url issue; the urls i specified as paths for the links were all from '/fc/locations..' or '/fc/layouts/...' I just had to remove the FC and put the controller as the first directory, eg: 'locations/...' for locationscontroller, 'layout/..' for layoutcontroller...as simple as that!! Thanks for all your help, I wish I could return the favor somehow, this was very critical for me...thanks so much :)

Comment: Glad to have helped. I'm not sure what you mean with 'put the controller as first directory', but if you follow [book.cakephp.org](http://book.cakephp.org) especially when it comes to conventions, everything is working :) - PS. Change your original post to include correct path now and say how it works so it can be a pointer for other people in the future.

Answer (score 0):

i sorted the issue out. It was because in my code, the previous user had made a controller file Locationscontroller.php and specified urls like this:

```
<form id ="0" action="/FC/locations/confirm_final">
```

This was for localhost in my local machine where the base folder was htdocs I had to type localhost/FC/ to access index.php. 
So naturally Since on EC2 I had made FC itself my base folder, it was trying to access another FC inside it which didn't exist. The /XXX/locations/  means it searches for "XXX" controller and then locations inside it. Since my controller was Locations, it kept giving an error.

As soon as I changed it to this:

```
<form id ="0" action="/locations/confirm_final">
```

It pointed to the right controller which was locations.
It was all because I didn't check which controller was called by which View!
I'm an idiot, that'll be all :D

Comment: So how does the form post url have anything to do with your js and img folders not displaying properly like you say in your original post?

Comment: the js and img urls were also preceded with an extra /FC/...just had to remove that! :D